# dynamic page in WordPress

Tags: php

Hi i need some advise as a newbie,
I have a table of brands in database and page with all brands icon 
when i click in a brand icon i want to be redirected to a dynamic page that load content from database according to the brand icon i clicked

I want to know if is it possible to do it in WordPress and if it's better than static pages and if there is any plugins i can use?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are the brands in the WordPress database? If so, are they a custom post type (posts, page, etc)?

Comment: yes in wp_brands table in WordPress database and they are not pages or posts. what i want it's like this page https://www.goodeed.com/brands

Comment: Is the wp_brands table your own custom table?

Comment: yes it's my own table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `wp_brands` is your own custom table, I would recommend passing the brand the user clicks on via Query String:

```
http://example.com/your/permalink/?brand=xyz
```

You can access this via PHP in your page template(not the wp-admin editor) like this:

```
$_GET['brand'];
```

Once you have that you can use whichever brand the user chose to query the database. This isn't the "WordPress" way of doing things, but it will solve the issue.

Comment: is there any chance for doing it in the WordPress way ?because now the website is local but how the permanlink will work after the website will be online ?